# Bind a cell in one Excel sheet to a cell in another

Tags: vba, excel, binding, bind

Say I had two Excel sheets (**ONE**.xlsx & **TWO**.xlsx). Would it be possible to have a certain cell in **ONE** to be changed at the same time as a certain cell in **TWO**?

For example:
B2 in **ONE** is equal to "Tuesday". Is there a way to make D10 in **TWO** also equal to "Tuesday" without having to go into **TWO** and manually changing it.

The more I think about this problem the more I think that it's not likley to work. The only way I can think of it working is by connecting them both up to the same database somehow. Thought I'd try you guys before I give up try something else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just open them both up in Excel and in book TWO, go to the cell you want and type `=` and then go to the cell in book ONE and click on it as you would with any other formula attached to any other cell...

Comment: If you type `=A1` in any cell, that binds *that* cell to `A1` (same worksheet & same workbook).  If you type `='Sheet1'!A1` in any cell, that binds *that* cell to `Sheet1!A1` (same workbook file). If you put `=[Two.xlsx]'Sheet1'!A1` then that will bind it to a the cell `A1` on `Sheet1` in the workbook `Two.xlsx`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Unfortunatly i couldn't get either of your solutions to work, I have however found another method: copy the cell I want to link to from ONE, then paste it into TWO using the "Paste Link" option. This now means that when the cell in ONE is changed, the changes are also made in TWO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, open both workbooks.

- put = in workbook 2 minimize and find the sheet/cell in workbook one
  select it.

  - close workbook 2 and save.
  - change the value in workbook 1
  - open workbook to (enable the security to look at workbook 1)
  - see the updated value.

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work when using two different spreadsheets unfortunately.

Comment: a work book is a different spreadsheet.  I tried this in excel 2010 and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution that works very well.

- Open both the workbooks.
- In the source workbook, copy the cell(s) that you wish to link.
- In the destination workbook, right click and select "Paste Link".

The cells in the destination workbook should now be linked so that when changes are made to the source workbook the changes are also made in the destination workbook.